# Break up into smaller functions MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I have the following function

```
 function registerUser(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let userData = {
        username: $('#formRegister input[name=username]').val(),
        password: $('#formRegister input[name=passwd]').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: kinveyBaseUrl + "user/" + kinveyAppKey + "/",
        headers: kinveyAppAuthHeaders,
        data: JSON.stringify(userData),
        success: registerSuccess,
        error: handleAjaxError
    });
    function registerSuccess(userInfo) {
        saveAuthInSession(userInfo);
        showHideMenuLinks();
        listBooks();
        showInfo('User registration successful.');

    }
}
```

I'm trying to do it in the following way: Direction Controllers contains RegisterUserController.js file with 1 function:

```
function registerUser(event) {
event.preventDefault();
let userData = {
    username: $('#formRegister input[name=username]').val(),
    password: $('#formRegister input[name=passwd]').val()
};
registerUserAjaxRequest();
function registerSuccess(userInfo) {
    saveAuthInSession(userInfo);
    showHideMenuLinks();
    listBooks();
    showInfo('User registration successful.');
   }
}
```

In other Direction Models contains RegisterUserModel.js file with this function:

```
function registerUserAjaxRequest() {
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: kinveyBaseUrl + "user/" + kinveyAppKey + "/",
    headers: kinveyAppAuthHeaders,
    data: JSON.stringify(userData),
    success: registerSuccess,
    error: handleAjaxError
}});
```

Guess what, it's working only if ajax request is in the regusterUser function. The question is: How can i break up into smaller functions and runs correctly ?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

That's the solution i've created. Im not sure its a good practice.

That's the register model:

```
  function registerUserModel(userData) {
   return $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: kinveyBaseUrl + "user/" + kinveyAppKey + "/",
        headers: kinveyAppAuthHeaders,
        data: JSON.stringify(userData),
        error: handleAjaxError
    });
}
```

And here is register user controller

```
function registerUser(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let userData = {
        username: $('#formRegister input[name=username]').val(),
        password: $('#formRegister input[name=passwd]').val()
    };
    registerUserModel(userData).then(function (userInfo) {
        saveAuthInSession(userInfo);
        showHideMenuLinks();
        showHomeView();
    })
}
```